# react + typescript How to fix props type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

**Development environment**
・react
・typescript
・styled-components

**Question**
Open is passed from the parent component to the child component below.

```
<RightNav open={open}/>
```

The following error occurs at the child component ①.
If there is someone who understands, please teach me

> 

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Ul = styled.ul<{open: boolean}>`
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  li {
    padding: 18px 10px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: #0D2538;
    position: fixed;
    transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX()100%'};
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 3.5rem;

    li {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }
`
const RightNav = () => {
  return (
   // ①　Ul in error
    <Ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Us</li>
      <li>Contact Us</li>
      <li>Sign Up</li>
      <li>Sign In</li>
    </Ul>
  )
}

export default RightNav
```

```
  ①  [ts] Property 'open' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; }' but required in type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLUListElement>, HTMLUListElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | "key" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" | "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 247 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 255 more ... | "open"> & Partial<...>, "sl...'. [2741]
    RightNav.tsx(4, 23): 'open' is declared here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the open prop to your component, then pass it to the styled component

```
const RightNav = ({open}) => {
  return (
    <Ul open={open}>
```

if you notice... the type definition for your styled component requires the `open` property

```
const Ul = styled.ul<{open: boolean}>`
-----------------------^-------------
```

And the parent renders this component with the open prop

```
<RightNav open={open}/>
-----------^---------
```

So you just need to accept that prop in your component and then pass to the `Ul` styled component :)